# Mouse wheel scroll transition not working from overflow to page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

The website does have a fixed element with `overflow:auto`. When a user positions the mouse over this element and scrolls, the element scrolls just fine. However, when the element is scrolled to the end, the page does not automatically take over the scroll. Instead, the user has to wait for about 1 second and then scroll again until the scrolling from the document takes over.

How can I make this transition smooth without the need of a scroll pause?

*PS: An example of this is also the "Similar questions" box on stackoverflow.*

Answer (score 1):

When a container with overflow set to auto or scroll, only when the content within that container has reached its end will the scroll propagate to the parent or the main document. use javascript to detect the end of the content by adding an `event_listener` as:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    if (container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === 
      container.clientHeight) {
        // Container has reached its scroll limit, propagate the scroll to the page
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent container from scrolling
        window.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY); // Scroll the page
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is the other way round. The document scroll does not immediately pass over the scroll event to the overlay, neither is `mouseenter` triggered on the overlay when the mouse is positioned over the overlay due to scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

**capture the scroll event on the fixed element and pass it to the main document seamlessly like:**

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
let scrolling = false;

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  scrolling = true;
});

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  scrolling = false;
});

container.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  if (scrolling) {
    if (container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === container.clientHeight) {
      // Container has reached its scroll limit, propagate the scroll to the page
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent container from scrolling
      window.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY); // Scroll the page
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, that if you beginn scrolling while hovering the document, once the mouse reaches the overlay container, `mouseenter` is NOT triggered as long as you just scroll and don't move your mouse (or pause scrolling for 1 second)